# How to align the items in navbar created by bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I can't shift the nav-items to the end even after applying !important in the css file. Which command is overriding?

CSS:  .nav-item{display: flex; justify-content: end !important;}

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown link
            </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is the code.I tried to modify this but it didn't work. As far as I know !important has higher specificity. How to change the alignment without changing the smaller screen alignment( which has a menu)?

Comment: what do you mean by aligning?? did you mean align to the right? And why didn't you just include that css rule inside your demo?? if you do, it will correctly align the `.nav-items` to the right... and if it doesn't in your real scenario is because you have probably a rule overriding it not belonging to bootstrap

Comment: can you show the CSS code you're using in the `.navbar-nav` and `.navbar-collapse` classes as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to align your menu items like this:

[image: target menu layout]

Then you need to know that, to function properly, `justify-content` needs to be added on your *container* class, not on your items.

Therefore, your CSS code is working as expected, but it seems that `<ul class="navbar-nav">` container is fitting the content, that's why you don't see it.

[image: navbar-collapse container full width]

[image: ul container fitting content]

So, to fix it, you need to:

- either move your CSS code `display: flex; justify-content: end !important;` to `.navbar-collapse` CSS class
- or move it to `.navbar-nav`, and add `.ms-auto` class to your `<ul>`, as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77678860/6515775

Answer (score 0):

use the class **ms-auto** in ul
check the below code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```